# cannot run virtualbox on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I tried to install virtualbox for the first time on my ubuntu 16.04 machine following the instructions [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/). When tried to run from terminal with command `virtualbox` it gave me the error below:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

and when tried to run by searching `virtualbox` an icon appeared in sidebar and after some seconds disappeared.

I tried downloading the official `deb` file form [the virtualbox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and install with `sudo apt install ./virtual...` but the same error happened.

I also completely removed virtualbox with `--purge` option and its user and group every time I tried to reinstall.

The interesting part is that it was easy to install the `Virtualbox` on an `ubuntu 16.04` hosted by another virtualbox on a `windows` machine.

Any answer or comment would be appreciated.

**Edit (Solved)**
Thanks to [Charles](https://askubuntu.com/users/283721/charles-green) the problem solved by changing the owner and group of `/usr` and `/usr/lib` to root by the following commands:

`sudo chown root:root /usr`
`sudo chown root:root /usr/lib`

My problem was that I only changed the owner by `sudo chown root /usr`.

Comment: There is a similar error on the [virtualbox forums](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759) - can you enter the command `ls -ld /usr && ls -ld /usr/lib` and append the results to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the link and the command. Problem solved. @CharlesGreen

Comment: @CharlesGreen Please add an answer providing your successful solution for the OP to accept, so this can be closed.

Comment: So you previously changed the owners of `/usr` and `/usr/lib` to someone who is not `root`? Remember not to do that again.

Comment: @edwinksl I can't imagine that it's very good practice, but it is possible that some installation routine given sudo access may have made the change.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Ya you could be right. If that is the case, hopefully OP can figure which package did that...

Comment: @edwinksl I hardly think that I did this before, maybe as Charles said it was some installation routine did that.

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned at [VirtualBox Forums](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759) the owner and group of `/usr` and / or `/usr/lib` may have been incorrectly set.

Check the two directories with `ls -ld /usr && ls -ld /usr/lib` - both the user and group of the directories should be `root`.  If not, they can be set with:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr /usr/lib
```

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: @TobiasK It didn't work for me either. I had to remove and reinstall virtualbox to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that also directories permissions matter.
I've got the same error even with the correct owner root:root (after chown): the problem was the access level (777):

```
ls -ld /usr/lib
drwxrwxrwx 182 root root 20480 dic 19 15:50 /usr/lib
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib
ls -ld /usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x 182 root root 20480 dic 19 15:50 /usr/lib
```

Once changed to 755 virtualbox started without problems.
 Just as a reference in case anyone have the same issue.

Surely Virtualbox users could benefit of a more specific error message
(and how/when owner and permissions of the directories were changed is still something to clarify)

Comment: does not woek for me