# VirtualBox does not run after ugrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, 18.04, permissions, virtualbox

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.

When I want to run VirtualBox from command line,it does not work. It returns the error:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

I have reinstalled VirtualBox but it still does not work.

Of course I have checked some solutions on Stack Exchange.

- [cannot run virtualbox on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947189/cannot-run-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I have executed the commands `sudo chown root:root /usr` and `sudo chown root:root /usr/lib` but it did not help me.

Here are the permission conditions of my `/usr` directory

```
ls -l / | grep usr
drwxrwxrwx 14 root root 4096  usr
ls -l /usr | grep lib
drwxr-xr-x 180 root root 20480  lib
ls -l /usr/lib | grep virtualbox
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096  virtualbox
ls -l /usr/lib/virtualbox | grep  
合計 80376
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 11月 27 23:44 ExtensionPacks
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10400 10月 10 22:27 VBoxAuth.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    22976 10月 10 22:27 VBoxAuthSimple.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   116920 10月 10 22:27 VBoxAutostart
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   166416 10月 10 22:27 VBoxBalloonCtrl
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    80048 10月 10 22:27 VBoxBugReport
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   993704 10月 10 22:27 VBoxCpuReport
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1875080 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDD.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   358376 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDD2.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      592 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDD2R0.r0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      412 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDD2RC.rc
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   225880 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDDR0.r0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   180432 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDDRC.rc
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   426528 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDDU.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    10312 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDTrace
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   162848 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDbg.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    35120 10月 10 22:27 VBoxDragAndDropSvc.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2097152  7月  3 00:34 VBoxEFI32.fd
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2097152  7月  3 00:34 VBoxEFI64.fd
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    59616 10月 10 22:27 VBoxExtPackHelperApp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    18648 10月 10 22:27 VBoxGuestControlSvc.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    35224 10月 10 22:27 VBoxGuestPropSvc.so
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VBoxHeadless
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    97184 10月 10 22:27 VBoxHeadless.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    18512 10月 10 22:27 VBoxHostChannel.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    70056 10月 10 22:27 VBoxKeyboard.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1091808 10月 10 22:27 VBoxManage
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   825640 10月 10 22:27 VBoxManageHelp
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root    26792 10月 10 22:27 VBoxNetAdpCtl
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VBoxNetDHCP
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   130680 10月 10 22:27 VBoxNetDHCP.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VBoxNetNAT
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   282792 10月 10 22:27 VBoxNetNAT.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   192264 10月 10 22:27 VBoxOGLhostcrutil.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   156552 10月 10 22:27 VBoxOGLhosterrorspu.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   172608 10月 10 22:27 VBoxOGLrenderspu.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   209688 10月 10 22:27 VBoxPython.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   209688 10月 10 22:27 VBoxPython3_6m.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   772328 10月 10 22:27 VBoxREM.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2969672 10月 10 22:27 VBoxRT.so
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSDL
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   167400 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSDL.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6571512 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSVC
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    47616 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSharedClipboard.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1096608 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSharedCrOpenGL.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    39400 10月 10 22:27 VBoxSharedFolders.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4163  8月 14 20:44 VBoxSysInfo.sh
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   108704 10月 10 22:27 VBoxTestOGL
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    10232 10月 10 22:27 VBoxTunctl
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3565336 10月 10 22:27 VBoxVMM.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VBoxVMMPreload
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10456 10月 10 22:27 VBoxVMMPreload.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    10232 10月 10 22:27 VBoxVolInfo
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1147120 10月 10 22:27 VBoxXPCOM.so
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    43656 10月 10 22:27 VBoxXPCOMC.so
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26784 10月 10 22:27 VBoxXPCOMIPCD
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1800968 10月 10 22:27 VMMR0.r0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1431668 10月 10 22:27 VMMRC.rc
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root   157776 10月 10 22:27 VirtualBox
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12015496 10月 10 22:27 VirtualBox.so
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 11月 27 23:46 __pycache__
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 11月 27 23:44 components
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   126032 10月 10 22:27 libvboxjxpcom.so
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 11月 27 23:44 sdk
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1778584 10月 10 22:27 vbox-img
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121912 10月 10 22:27 vboxshell.py
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19992296 10月 10 22:27 vboxwebsrv
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14895472 10月 10 22:27 webtest
```

And here is the result when I execute `ldd /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0f7dd000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fb30a900000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb30a6e3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb30a4c4000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb30a2bc000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb30a0b8000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fb309cf7000)
libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007fb309a7a000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fb309810000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fb309398000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb30900f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb308df7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb308a06000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb30b015000)
libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007fb30864f000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fb308429000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb30808b000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007fb307e66000)
libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fb307c49000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007fb307a2d000)
libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007fb30781f000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007fb3075e9000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fb307284000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fb307039000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fb306de7000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fb306bd9000)
libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007fb305030000)
libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fb304cb2000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007fb304a7e000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fb3047fd000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fb3044ce000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fb3042bb000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fb303fe5000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fb303db3000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fb303baf000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fb3039a4000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fb303789000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007fb30356e000)
libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007fb30332d000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fb303125000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fb302f21000)
libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007fb302d18000)
libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007fb302a8b000)
libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007fb3027e9000)
libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007fb3025b3000)
libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007fb30239d000)
libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007fb302174000)
libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007fb301f65000)
libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007fb301d1b000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fb301a12000)
```

and here  below is the result of `dpkg -l | grep vir`

```
ii  libvirt0:amd64                                4.0.0-1ubuntu8.5                            amd64        library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii  qemu-kvm                                      1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.7                      amd64        QEMU Full virtualization on x86 hardware
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox                        0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1                 all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virt-manager                                  1:1.5.1-0ubuntu1.1                          all          desktop application for managing virtual machines
ii  virt-viewer                                   6.0-2                                       amd64        Displaying the graphical console of a virtual machine
ii  virtinst                                      1:1.5.1-0ubuntu1.1                          all          Programs to create and clone virtual machines
ii  virtualbox                                    5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                               5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1                 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                                 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

When I execute  `dpkg -S /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so`, the result will be

```
virtualbox: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so
```

What should I do to run VirtualBox again？

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so` to determine parent package of this library.

Comment: It returned "virtualbox: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so"

Comment: N0rbert, I have added the result.Do you know the answear？

Comment: No, I don't. But you can try to install Oracle's package (see [instruction](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)).

Comment: I have done, but same problem occured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)

Comment: thank you,.though i have solved the problem in another way.

Comment: To help other users you may want to share your method as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the problem.
It is just a permission problem of usr directory.
I have just executed the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr
```

All has been done after that.

Comment: Do you know which /usr binary had the wrong permission? `/usr`is a dir, and not a file.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited